# I'm compiling a modified Linux kernel in Ubuntu; can I recover from a corrupted kernel if I boot into recovery mode?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, safe-mode

I have installed Ubuntu from wubi.exe along-side windows, and I am a new user to it.

If my kernel has an error after modifying it and replacing the previous one, does the "safe" option in my bootloader recover my kernel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with wubi, but usually you just add another kernel and leave the existing ones where they are in case you need them later.

Answer (score 0):

If you build your kernel following the proper procedures for building Ubuntu kernels (I don't know what they are), then when you install the resulting `.deb` packages you'll get an additional entry in the GRUB boot menu. Your old kernel(s) will still be there unless you explicitly remove them.

Recovery mode isn't a special kernel. It just boots a minimal system, using whatever kernel it's paired with.

Comment: I'm not an Ubuntu user, but I don't think it's common to package a kernel in a .deb for local use. It makes more sense when distributing it to a (large) number of computers.

Comment: @Eroen: Actually, it's a perfectly normal way. Ubuntu provides easy tools (you don't have to start from scratch) and the approach is often recommended on Ask Ubuntu or the Ubuntu Forums. IMHO, the benefits of making a `.deb` far outweigh the benefits of spending a little extra time--only a minute or two extra once you know what you're doing. Having un-packaged software on your machine that you're not developing is a recipe for problems down the road.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about the noise. Different distros, different tools ;)